# How to fill a list with vectors of different length?

Tags: r, list, loops, lapply

My task is to create a `list` containing 100 vectors: `c(1)`, `c(1,2)`, `c(1,2,3)`, ... , `c(1:100)`.

I tried to do it using a `for` loop, but I don't know how.

If possible, I would like a solution using the `lapply` function.

Comment: Each vector should be assigned to consecutive elements of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `seq_len`.

```
> lapply(1:100, seq_len)
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 1 2

[[3]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[4]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

[[5]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

[[6]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6

[[7]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

[[8]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

[[9]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[10]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

...
```

Comment: Great solution, thank you! And just out of curiosity, how would it work if I initialized an empty list (`myList <- list()`) before `lapply` and executed `lappy` on it? I mean something like this: `lapply(myList, function(x) {here code to initialize myList})`

Comment: @John Not sure if I can follow, wile in `for` loops you have to initialize, `lapply` takes care of that itself and nothing has to be initialized `myList <- lapply(lapply(1:100, seq_len))`. Anyways, a list of specific length can be initialized using `vector(mode='list', length=100L)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it should look using `for` loop. However, the above solutions with `lapply` are more preferred in R.

```
myList <- list()
for(i in 1:100) {
  myList[[i]] <- c(1:i)
}
```

Output:

```
> myList
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 1 2

[[3]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[4]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

[[5]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
lapply(1:100, function(x) 1:x)
```

Or

```
lapply(1:100, \(x) 1:x)
```

It will return

```
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 1 2

[[3]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[4]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

[[5]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
Etc...
```